# Looping through Rows to Validate their Content with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a xls-file which contains several date-columns. I change the background-color of the rows depending on the content of the row.

1. No content = no color
2. Not valid datetime = red
3. Valid datetime = green

Here is my problem: When i enter a invalid value on row 10 and 100. Every row from 7 to 100 is getting checked and 10th and 100th row is colored red. (I start at row 7 because there are some headerrows). When i now delete the text in the 100th row. The loop only goes to the 10th row and ends. Obviously because 10 is the last used row. But the 100th row is still colored in red.
Thats because my loop colors the rows wihtout content to no color. And i only loop through the columns that have values.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Here is my VB-Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    CheckAllDateCells
End Sub
Private Sub CheckAllDateCells()
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "T", 7    
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "V", 7    
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "X", 7    
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "Y", 7    
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AI", 7   
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AJ", 7   
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AK", 7   
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AL", 7   
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AM", 7   
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AN", 7   
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AO", 7   
    CheckDateCellsForColumn "AP", 7   
End Sub
Private Sub CheckDateCellsForColumn(column As String, firstRowIndex As Long)
    For i = firstRowIndex To Me.Range(column & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        CheckDateCell i, Me.Range(column & 1).column
    Next i
End Sub
Private Sub CheckDateCell(ByVal rowIndex As Long, ByVal columnIndex As Long)
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).value) Then
        If IsDate(Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).value) Then
            If Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).value Like "##.##.####" Then
                Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Else
                Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Else
            Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Else
        Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Maybe i can achive this wihtout using vb? only conditional formatting?

---

conditional formatting just gives me the possibillity to color cells on specific criteria, like date is yesterday or date is from this month etc. But i can not select a daterange by myself like date is between 01.01.1899 and 01.01.2999...

Comment: Please remember to check a tag's description before adding it to your question. VB.NET is not the same thing as VBA.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you basically need to just reset all the cells to "No Colour" - if it's a viable quick fix, just say something like `cells(1, column).EntireColumn.Interior.Color = xlNone` at the very start? Or even just stick a `+100` on your `For i = firstRowIndex To Me.Range(column & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row` line to make it loop 100 rows past the last row

Comment: I'm with @jamheadart.  I'd recommend resetting your entire column to no color at the beginning of the macro used to shade the invalid rows.

Comment: cells(1, column).EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 0; works, But it takes a little bit too long. I have to wait like 2 seconds. This makes a bad workflow. For the first, i will stick to the +100 on my loop if i will not find a better solution.

Comment: Does this have to be VBA?  This can be done with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: @pnuts i dont know what you mean by 'contains both'. either the value is '##.##.####' or the format is invalid.

Comment: @tigeravatar not it does not. How can i do this wiht conditional formatting? I would really appreciate not to use vb

Comment: could the downvoter at least tell me the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick + 100 to your loop count so that it goes 100 rows past the last row that contains data (but this looping through empty cells so is a bit "hacky")

`For i = firstRowIndex To Me.Range(column & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 100`

You can reset the entire column right at the start (but this is proving to be slow - EntireColumn is a big object!):

`cells(1, column).EntireColumn.Interior.Color = xlNone`

Best idea is a combo of both - reset the Range you're doing in one go using the last row + 100 so no looping further than required (100 being a sortof arbitrary number assuming you don't delete more than 100 rows before running, could easily be 1000 which is still tiny compared to "EntireColumn")

```
Private Sub CheckDateCellsForColumn(column As String, firstRowIndex As Long)
Dim lROW As Long: lROW = Me.Range(column & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Me.Range(column & firstRowIndex & ":" & column & lROW + 100).Interior.Color = 0
    For i = firstRowIndex To lROW
        CheckDateCell i, Me.Range(column & 1).column
    Next i
End Sub
```